# Isn't polymorphism works wrong in JS ES

Tags: javascript, oop, polymorphism, ecma

I'm currently working on a browser extension to manage opened tabs and I notice that in JS ES polymorphism works a bit strange when I declare class fields at the top of the class.

Let say that we want to use polymorphism in object initialization.

E.g. we have base class **View**:

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { }
}
```

and derived class **TabView**:

```js
class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }

    init() {
        this.title = "test";
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }
}
```

Now lets try to call simple script in index file to debug this example.

```js
const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

Call stack for this example looks right(read from up do down):

- TabView constructor
- View construstor (invoked by super())
- TabView init() (View constructor invoke overwriten init method from TabView)

**Expected values for TabView**:

- _viewModel: "model"
- _title: "test"

**This example values for TabView**:

- _viewModel: "model"
- _title: "undefined"

When I debug this example, it looks like when `init()` method is invoked from `View` then `this` refers to `View` class instead of `TabView`. The value was saved in `View` instance, and `TabView` field was still 'undefined'. When I removed `_title` field from the top of `TabView` class then everything works as I want. Result was the same for the newest version of Firefox and Microsoft Edge.

I like to have class fields written at the top, so I want to ask if is it correct behavior of JS ES or maybe it is a bug that maybe will be correcter in future version of ECMA Script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I debug this example, it looks like when `init()` method is invoked from `View` then `this` refers to `View` class instead of `TabView`. The value was saved in `View` instance, and `TabView` field was still `'undefined'`.

Take a look at this code:

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { console.log("View init"); }
}

class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }

    init() {
        console.log("TabView init");
        this.title = "test";
    }

    get title() {
        console.log("get title");
        return this._title;
    }
    
    set title(value) {
        console.log("set title");
        this._title = value;
    }
}

const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

This logs

```
TabView init
set title
get title
```

Which means the constructor calls `init` from `TabView` which in turn calls the setter for `title`.

The reason `_title` is `undefined` in the end is [the specification for class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/b0784d98fdab4d83b8b6e4558702cd7b8598976b/README.md#fields-without-initializers-are-set-to-undefined) (a Stage 3 proposal, at the time of writing). Here is the relevant part:

> #### Fields without initializers are set to `undefined`
>
> Both public and private field declarations create a field in the instance, whether or not there's an initializer present. If there's no initializer, the field is set to `undefined`. This differs a bit from certain transpiler implementations, which would just entirely ignore a field declaration which has no initializer.

Because `_title` is not initialised within `TabView`, the spec defines that its value should be `undefined` after the constructor finishes executing.

You have a few options here but if you want to declare `_title` as a class field **and** have a different value for it, you have to give the field a value as part of the `TabView` instantiation, not as part of its parent (or grandparents, etc.).

#### Field initialiser

```
class TabView extends View {
    _title = "test"; //give value to the field directly

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { }
}

class TabView extends View {
    _title = "test"; //give value to the field directly

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }
}

const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

#### Initialise the value in the constructor

```
class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
        this._title = "test"; //give value to `_title` in the constructor
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { }
}

class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
        this._title = "test"; //give value in the constructor
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }
}

const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

#### Call a method that initialises the field

```
class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
        this.init(); //call `init` which will give value to the `_title` field
    }
    
    init() {
      this.title = "test";
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { }
}

class TabView extends View {
    _title;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
        this.init(); //call `init` which will give value to the `_title` field
    }
    
    init() {
      this.title = "test";
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }
}

const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

#### Remove the field declaration

```
class TabView extends View {
    //no declaration here

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

```js
class View {
    _viewModel;

    constructor(viewModel) {
        this._viewModel = viewModel;
        this.init();
    }

    init() { console.log("View init"); }
}

class TabView extends View {
    //no declaration here

    constructor(viewModel) {
        super(viewModel);
    }

    init() {
        this.title = "test";
    }

    get title() {
        return this._title;
    }
    
    set title(value) {
        this._title = value;
    }
}

const tabView = new TabView("model");
console.log(tabView.title);
```

Comment: Ok, so it mean that JS ES works as it should with specification. I thought that it should works similar to compiled languages e.g. virtual method in C#. I tested the same solution in equivalent C# code and it works as I thought it should in JS.

In C# when you invoke overridden method, than `this`  still refers to deriviated class, but in JS it refers to base class which invoke deriviated method.
So JS instead of initialize my field in deriviated class declaration, crate new field in base class that is hidden by my 'undefined' field.

Thanks for your answer, it explained me everything.

Comment: No, that's incorrect. If you have `class B extends A` in JavaScript, then invoking `new B()` *never* refers to `A`. A new object is created for `this` and it's then passed to the constructor of `A` to be modified (e.g., properties added, instantiation done) but *isn't* `A` (there is no instance of `A` created). At the end of the construction process you only have a `B` object and in-between you may have not fully instantiated `B` object but not an `A`. The spec for fields just mandates that they are `undefined` if not initialised in the current creation chain, that's unrelated to instances.